# Hashing - inserting a value into the hash table

Tags: python, hash

Can anyone help me fix my put function which inserts a value into the hash table?
Right now I'm getting an output of a hash table full of None's
e.g. [None, None, None, None, None]

```
class BasicHashTable:
def __init__(self,size=7):
    self.size = size
    self.slots = [None] * self.size

def hash_function(self, key):
    return key%len(self.slots)

def rehash(self, old_pos):
    return (old_pos + 1) % self.size

def put(self, key):
    hash_value = key%len(self.slots)    
    probe_seq=[]     
    insert_pos=hash_value     
    probe_seq+=[insert_pos]     
    probes=1     
    while(self.slots[insert_pos]!=None):         
        probes+=1         
        insert_pos=(insert_pos+1)%len(self.slots)         
        probe_seq+=[insert_pos]     
        self.slots[insert_pos]=key     
    return insert_pos
```

Testing:

```
hash_t = BasicHashTable() 
hash_t.put(3)
hash_t.put(20)
hash_t.put(10)
print(hash_t.slots)
```

Gives [None, None, None, 3, 10, None, 20]

Comment: can you put your test code?

Comment: Does it give you [None, None, None, None, None] or [None, None, None, 3, 10, None, 20]? Make up your mind.

Comment: @stefan I think that is a test case, not a currently outputted value.

Comment: Side-note: Never use `==`/`!=` to compare to `None` (a singleton). Change `!= None` to `is not None` and `== None` to `is None`, so you get identity based tests (basically, pointer equality) rather than invoking the more expensive rich comparison machinery for nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It is not adding to the map because in the beginning, the slots are all `None`, so the code in the while never executes. This code includes the code that assigns the value to the slot. You could fix this by doing:

```
# code
while(self.slots[insert_pos]!=None):         
    #code  
self.slots[insert_pos]=key  # unindented
# code
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Firstly you should make use of the rehash method you created. So if the key can't be inserted right away you will generate a new hash. You will keep doing this until you find an empty slot, then you will insert your key into that slot.

```
def put(self, key):
    insert_pos = self.hash_function(key)
    if self.slots[insert_pos] == None:
        self.slots[insert_pos] = key
    else:
        insert_pos = self.rehash(insert_pos)
        while self.slots[insert_pos] != None and self.slots[insert_pos] != key:
            insert_pos = self.rehash(insert_pos)
        if self.slots[insert_pos] == None:
            self.slots[insert_pos] = key
```

Once all the slots are filled, if you attempt to add a new key the program will loop indefinitely; I'll let you find a solution to this problem. You will likely find the solution when you start adding data to your keys.

Also you should make use of the size attribute you created as so:

```
def hash_function(self, key):
    return key%self.size
```